# PayPal buttons callback to update database

Tags: jquery, cordova, web, paypal

I'm implementing a PayPal button for my website and i want to make a secure ajax call to my server, to update my database, after the transaction is done. I have to pass the ID of the row to update. How can i implement such callback?

Comment: What have you tried? PayPal provides an [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) for this, you'll need to create a server-side page on your website that contains the update logic once it receives the notification of successful payment.

Comment: I have tried to implement a listener in the code of my web page but i don't think it's a secure way to do this. With IPN can i pass through post method any of my variables defined in my code?

Comment: Yes, PayPal provides example IPN scripts on a [github repo](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples) that you might find useful.